# Gitlab CI variable, option with quotes

Tags: gitlab, pytest

I have the following `gitab-ci.yml file`:

```
stages:
  - tests

.test: &test_job
    image:
      name: test.com/test:latest
      entrypoint: [""]
    script:
    - py.test /test  -v $EXTRA_OPTIONS 

testing:
  variables:
    EXTRA_OPTIONS: -m "not slow"
  <<: *test_job
  stage: tests
```

I would like to pass option to run pytest like:
`py.test /tests -v -m "not slow"`
to avoid running slow tests, but gitlab is trying to escape quotes.
I've got something like:
`py.test /tests -v -m '"not\' 'slow"'`

is it possible to create a variable that would be inlined without escaping?
All I found it's [this link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1941#note_20890073) but it does not help.

Comment: AFAIK CI variables will always be escaped, and even worse: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27436

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to avoid whitespace escaping in the variable, use single quotes:

```
variables:
    EXTRA_OPTIONS: -m 'not slow'
```

To apply the additional command-line arguments, you have three options:

1. [`PYTEST_ADDOPTS`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#how-to-change-command-line-options-defaults). This is the simplest option IMO; just replace `EXTRA_OPTIONS` with `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` in the variables section:

```
variables:
    PYTEST_ADDOPTS: -m 'not slow'
```

2. Use `addopts` combined with `-o`. `addopts` is an inifile key that [enables you to persist command line args in `pytest.ini`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#adding-default-options). The `-o/--override-ini` arg allows one to override an inifile value, including `addopts`. The combination of both is a nifty trick to pass command line args via environment variables:

   ```
   script:
     - pytest -v -o "addopts=$EXTRA_OPTIONS" /test
   ```
3. Use `eval`:

   ```
   script:
     - eval pytest -v "$EXTRA_OPTIONS" /test
   ```

However, you need to be very careful when using `eval`; see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/2650249)
. I would thus prefer the first option.